# Spring Data JPA - Bind by Id instead objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is my code

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentTest")
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
List<LanguageRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would like to have something like this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentTest")
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
List<Long> languageRecordsIds = new ArrayList<>();
```

How to map by ID instead of object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve only the ID instead of the Entity of an association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212319/how-do-i-retrieve-only-the-id-instead-of-the-entity-of-an-association)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load only ids from Many to Many mapping tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999997/how-to-load-only-ids-from-many-to-many-mapping-tables)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999997/how-to-load-only-ids-from-many-to-many-mapping-tables) answers how to hold just id references.

To clarify what to do for your specific question, you would want to do:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "LanguageRecordTable", joinColumns=(@JoinColumn(name="<Column name of field to select from in LanguageRecordTable>"))
@Column(name = "<Name of id field to join on in this table>")
List<Long> languageRecordsIds;
```